# listview in android can't get value

Tags: android, listview

I have value in `ListView`, but I can't select any value

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 

             {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) 
                 {
                         try{                            
                             String phone = adapter.tvPhone.getText().toString();
                         }
                         catch(Exception e) {
                         System.out.println("error 1:: " + e );
                             Log.i(" error1 :: "+e,null);
                     }

                 }
             });"
```

Comment: Can tell what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match with the question itself. What you want to do and why you can't do it? Please, elaborate.

Comment: `"` after `;` — syntax error

Comment: Also, posting badly formatted code is not cool. To get nice answers one should make the question nice too.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 

             {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) 
                 {
                         try{                            
                             String phone =  list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phone, 1000).show();
                         }
                         catch(Exception e) {
                         System.out.println("error 1:: " + e );
                             Log.i(" error1 :: "+e,null);
                     }

                 }
             });"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only have text view as list items you can do:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) 
             {
                     try{                            
                         String phone = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                     }
                     catch(Exception e) {
                     System.out.println("error 1:: " + e );
                         Log.i(" error1 :: "+e,null);
                 }

             }
```

Comment: It's better to get data by index from data source, because when the view becomes something different, this code won't survive